# Azure functions better to call my API directly for sql server db access or use my azure API

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm posting because I don't think the azure functions can take advantage of connection pooling.  Say if I run 1 sql query every 5 minutes in my azure function, the initial connection will take a long time to connect because it can't take advantage of connection pooling like a C# web api that's always running.

Would it be better to call my C# Webapi to make that data call and return the results?  Or is it better to directly connect to the db?  Now if there are 10 or so DB calls I'm sure directly would be better, but 1 or 2 I don't know.

this is a C# azure function connecting to a azure sql server

Comment: If you just make 1 call per 5 minutes, how would connection pooling make any difference? If you made many simultaneous calls, Function would use connection pooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would only be applicable in the Consumption ("Serverless") Plan. Using the traditional App Service plan, your function would not be deprovisioned and would be able to make use of connection pooling since it is running on the same plan as an API App.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm using consumption.  Thank you so much for the answer.  That actually makes a big difference.  I suppose I just need to monitor the CPU and then memory then, and I'll be fine.